# Working with dlls in MSDN - books for reference?

Tags: dll

Despite having reasonable experience in C++, I am still pretty useless in setting up projects/workspaces for libraries, linking to libraries from the main project, setting up the project so that I can debug into them, etc.

I mainly use MSDN for development.

Does anybody know of any books which will explain
1. how to set up different kinds of projects 
2. how different files are generated during the compilation process and what they are for
3. how to set up your project so you can debug into libraries

There are loads of books and websites which teach you how to program in C++, but so far I cannot find any websites which explains how to make full use of the development environment. We have a small bookshop in town but I cannot find any books to that description either.

Thank you.

Comment: You mean you are using Visual Studio?

Answer (score 0):

[Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Unleashed](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0672329727) teaches you *most* of those things, although *not all* of them.